# PHP reducing repetition in a function

Tags: php, function, variables

I have a function that sets a class variable based on two conditions, that the variable isn't aready set, & that there's matching key in a passed array...

```
    private function setVariable($source, $key, &$target)
    {
        if(!isset($target) && isset($source[$key]))
            $target = $source[$key];
        $target = $target;
    }
```

called with...

```
    $this->setVariable($source, 'key', $this->key);
```

Alternatively...

```
    private function setVariable($source, $key, &$target)
    {
        if(!isset($target) && isset($source[$key]))
            return $source[$key];
        return $target;
    }
```

called with...

```
    $this->key = setVariable($source, 'key', $this->key);
```

However either seems to involve unnecessary repetition in calling `setVariable(...)`, especially considering the name of the variable being set is always the value of `$key`, so if `$key = 'wombat'` I'm setting `$this->wombat`.

Is there a way to rewrite it so that I call `setVariable(...)` doing something like one of these? ...

```
    $this->key = setVariable($source);
    $this->setVariable($source, 'key');
    $this->setVariable($source, $this->key);
```

**Note:** I could even leave `$source` out because `$source = $this->alwaysSameArray`, but I think leaving it in makes it clearer, & it certainly makes the code inside `setVariable(...)` more concise.

Comment: If `$target` is always `$key` on `$this`… `$this->$key = ...`…!?

Comment: Not sure your second version of `setVariable` logically makes sense, I would think this is more a `getVariable` method as it doesn't change the data.

Comment: I get what you're saying there, & have considered renaming that function entirely. Here I left both versions named the same for clarity in that they're both doing the same thing, assigning a value to the target variable.

Comment: @deceze, please put your comment as an answer so I can accept it as such. After a couple of mis-steps in implementing, `$this->$key` works. I've struggled to get my head around variable variables, & even now think I'm barely there enough to make this work.